# how do i get a specific attribute from an inherited class when using an array from another class?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I am new to Java programming and have encountered a slight problem.
I wrote tow Classes the first named `Human` and the second called `Student` which extends `Human`

So, in short, I created an array with the type `Human` and now I want to output a specific  attribute of `Student` and I want to check if the value of the array entered is a `Student`. The problem is that the array type  is `Human`, I can't ask for an exclusive `Student` attribute.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

**The Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (Menschen[i] instanceof Student) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + Menschen[i].getName() + ", Geschlecht" 
                           + Menschen[i].getGeschlecht() + ", Matrikelnummer: " 
                           + ", Typ: " + Menschen[i].getTyp());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name; " + Menschen[i].getName() + ", Geschlecht" 
                       + Menschen[i].getGeschlecht()+", Typ: "+Menschen[i].getTyp() + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you would do well to change the condition of the `for` loop to `i < Menschen.length` (instead of `i < 4`). That way, you will loop throught the whole array, independent of its size (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather from your question, I think you could solve this problem by casting your `Human` to `Student`.

So, inside your `if`:

`Student s = (Student) Menschen[i] ;`

And then you can access the `Student`'s attribute corresponding to your `Menschen[i]` by using the `Student s` reference. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @Bashir He is checking the identity of the object with `instanceof`, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much you solved the problem. Just learned about typecasting as well so it all makes sense now ^^.

Answer (score 1):

If using Java 14 you can do:

```
if (Menschen[i] instanceof Student student) {
    student.studentSpecificMethod();
} else {
  ...
}
```

*EDIT: for earlier Java versions see Mario MG's answer*

But generally it's rare that you should need `instanceof`. It's best to try coming up with a design for a general method that would be overridden in specific subclasses, whenever possible.

*EDIT2: you can get rid of the `i` counter completely*

```
for (Human mensch : Menschen) { //please name variables in lowercase, so Menschen -> menschen
    if (mensch instanceof Student student) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```